# delphi Invalid enum value '_24170'

Tags: delphi, enums

I have my dll, it contains function:

```
function GetPdfReport(
  //this is string representation of MyEnum
  AStringParam : Pchar
): TByteDynArray; stdcall; export;

var
//my vars

begin
  try
    try
      //i try to pass incorrect string value on purpose to get exception
      MyEnumVariable := TRttiEnumerationType.GetValue<MyEnum>(AStringParam);

      //code hide
    except
      on E : Exception do
        begin
          //log error
          Log.Error(E.ClassName + ' : ' + E.Message, 'errors');
        end;
    end;
  finally
    //dispose
  end;
```

Then i get exception:

> The InnerException message was 'Invalid enum value '_24170' cannot be
>   deserialized into type
>   'MyEnum'.

I want log exception message with string value that i passed as parameter but not some unclear numbers like '_24170'. How can I do this?

**Update:**

Let's say i have `MyEnum` with 3 values `(One, Two, Three)`, and when i pass to my function string `"Five"` i want to see exception like this:

> Invalid enum value 'Five' cannot be deserialized into type 'MyEnum'.

Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, look [passing incorrect string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFWGB.jpg), then [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezkOn.jpg), and my [enumType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMPjI.jpg) does not contain this string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code that you present does not raise an exception in case the supplied text does not match one of the enum values. Instead a value of `-1` is returned. Of course, `-1` is not a valid enum value so that makes `TRttiEnumerationType.GetValue` a rather questionable method if you wish to perform error handling.

You would need to test for this yourself. Rather than using `TRttiEnumerationType` it might be simpler to go directly to `GetEnumValue`, which returns an integer and so makes error checking a little simpler to write.

```
var
  OrdinalValue: Integer;
  Value: MyEnum;
....
OrdinalValue := GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(MyEnum), AStringParam);
if OrdinalValue = -1 then
  // handle error
Value := MyEnum(OrdinalValue);
```

Naturally you'd want to wrap this in a method to make it re-usable.

Comment: My dll work with soap web service and it seems that exception raised when i call web service method, anyway thanks for your answer it's very useful for me.